# tikz remember picture inside a latex table for posterior tikz drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, overlays

I am working in a latex table that has tikz figures in it. This is fine, however I want to use elements inside those independent figures to overlay an extra tikz figure on the top of the table. 
The option `[remember picutre]` seems helpful, but I can not figure out how to use it in the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\newcommand{\myCoord}[1]{
  \tikz[remember picture]{
    \coordinate (#1) at (0,0);
    \draw (#1) circle[radius=2pt];
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
  & A & B  & C  & D &\\ 
  a & \myCoord{aA} & \myCoord{aB} & \myCoord{aC} & \myCoord{aD}\\
  b & \myCoord{bA} & \myCoord{bB} & \myCoord{bC} & \myCoord{bD}\\ 
  c & \myCoord{cA} & \myCoord{cB} & \myCoord{cC} & \myCoord{cD}\\
  d & \myCoord{dA} & \myCoord{dB} & \myCoord{dC} & \myCoord{dD}\\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \draw (aA) -- (bC);
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Should the option be applied to

- `\tikz[remember picture]`
- `\coordinate[remember picture]`
- to the overlying tikz figure

Comment: You need `overlay` for second `tikzpicture` i. e. `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw (aA) -- (bC);
\end{tikzpicture}%`

Comment: You should also look at the `tikzmark` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `overlay` option for the second `tikzpicture`; this can be done either "globally" (i.e., for all the environment), by passing the option to the `tikzpicture` environment or locally (i.e., for selected constructs inside the environment), by passing the option to the desired commands (`\draw`, in your case).

So, in this case, both of the following options would give you the desired result (after the code stabilizes after two or three runs):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]]
  \draw (aA) -- (bC);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

or

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \draw[overlay] (aA) -- (bC);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Using the `tikzmark` library, as suggested in one comment, your code might look like this (some additional shifting will be required):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark} 

\newcommand{\myCoord}[1]{
  \tikzmark{#1}
    \tikz\draw (pic cs:#1) circle[radius=2pt];
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
  & A & B  & C  & D &\\ 
  a & \myCoord{aA} & \myCoord{aB} & \myCoord{aC} & \myCoord{aD}\\
  b & \myCoord{bA} & \myCoord{bB} & \myCoord{bC} & \myCoord{bD}\\ 
  c & \myCoord{cA} & \myCoord{cB} & \myCoord{cC} & \myCoord{cD}\\
  d & \myCoord{dA} & \myCoord{dB} & \myCoord{dC} & \myCoord{dD}\\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \draw[overlay] (pic cs:aA) -- (pic cs:bC);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```